# How to update range of dynamic fields in Solr 4?

Tags: json, solr, dynamic-data, solr4

I have the following field in a my Solr 4 schema

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<dynamicField name="rank_*" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Which I can update atomically using below this which works great and leaves other fields alone

```
{"add":{"doc":{"id":"111","rank_350":{"set":"1"},"rank_391":{"set":"4"}}},
 "add":{"doc":{"id":"222","rank_350":{"set":"1"},"rank_391":{"set":"4"}}}}
```

Now I want to clear any existing ranks before updating with new ones, without having to query what they are first.  If I use approach above and upated with just new rank the old two would remain there since update is atomic.

I have tried using the wildcard within one post or with other updates but solr thinks there is a field called rank_* rather than apply null setting to all ranks.

```
{"add":{"doc":{"id":"111","rank_*":{"set":"null"}}}
```

**How can I apply an update to all rank_* dynamic fields?**

Reason is I don't want to have to query first to see what was there before as I will be batch updating up to 200 at one time (this can be done in one post).  If I had to query that would be 201 posts rather than 1, or changing my event to know what had been removed which is also difficult.

Comment: are there any non-dynamic fields also (besides id) ? Should these non-dynamic fields retain their values even if a batch update is done?

Comment: yes and yes.  they retain values fine with adding new ranks atomically.

Comment: @dove Years have passed after you posted this question, but I am running into same exact situation with atomic indexing. May I ask what solution did you end up with finally?

Comment: @genonymous I had to go with my own solution, that is I know the all the potential dynamic fields to be updated, if one is not present in an update then I include but with a null set to clear it.  Does that make sense?  It saves reading before updating but only because I know the potential list of fields before I do, you may not be so lucky

Comment: @dove thanks for your reply. Yes, I am not so lucky. In my case these fields are generated dynamically and I can't know in advance what their names are going to be. Here is one thing that I am thinking of - create a custom Solr plugin that intercepts the indexing request. If there is * present in the indexing request for a field name, then query and retrieve the whole document, create a new document with all other fields intact but the fields that match the * pattern will be set to null and then this new document will be passed on for indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That I know of, the only field-related features in Solr that support wildcards are the fl parameter, dynamicField, and copyField.  Anything else, which includes all forms of indexing, can only reference one field at a time.  There is no way as far as I know to do exactly what you're trying to do.